# How to post parameter to Azure Service URL using WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, azure, post, parameters

I have tested/googled for hours on how to POST parameter in C# to an Azure Service without getting the Error 405.

The following code in C++ using Chilkat lib works fine

```
CkHttp http;    
CkHttpRequest req;
http.put_SessionLogFilename("c:/temp/httpLog.txt"); 
req.put_HttpVerb("POST");
req.put_Path("/api/test?value=1234");

CkHttpResponse *resp = http.SynchronousRequest("http://testservice.cloudapp.net",80,false,req);
if (resp == 0 )
    afxDump << http.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";

afxDump << resp->bodyStr() << "\r\n";
delete resp;
```

But if it uses this c# code i get the Error 405.

```
string uri = "http://testservice.cloudapp.net/api/test";
string parameter = "value=1234";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(uri, parameter);
}
```

Any hints what i do wrong?

Comment: try removing that content-type header ,  the code you have is valid . But I am not exactly sure how webclient embeds your parameter into the request , but I have a feeling that that content type may not be correct.  Also , that is the ony difference I can really see between the c+ version

Comment: Removing the ContentType specs results also the error 405.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be better off using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient` . By looking at what the C++ code does it should be something like this in C# using `HttpClient`

```
    public void Test() {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://testservice.cloudapp.net");
        var response = client.PostAsync("api/test?value=1234", new StringContent(string.Empty)).Result;
        var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        var errorText = response.ReasonPhrase;

        // response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); will throw an exception if status code does not indicate success

        var responseContentAsString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var responseContentAsBYtes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    }

}
```

Here is the async version of the code above

```
public async Task TestAsync() {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://testservice.cloudapp.net");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("api/test?value=1234", new StringContent(string.Empty));
            var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            var errorText = response.ReasonPhrase;

            // response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); will throw an exception if status code does not indicate success

            var responseContentAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseContentAsBYtes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: why is httpclient prefered?

Comment: @Scott Selby Because it's lightweight, supports async operations and gives you better control of request/response. It was implemented for using it with web apis in mind. This is the default route to go if you are accessing ASP.NET WebApi for instance.

Comment: @Heribert Scharnagl if you are the one who is building the API on the server side, why do you need to POST here. I thing this should be just a simple GET request because you are supplying the parameters in the query string.

Comment: @Mihail Shishkov: my POST will add some data in a database, with PUT i change them and with GET i read the values

Comment: Is there a solution with WebClient? I've to use .net 4.0 and there is no HttpClient available.

Comment: HttpClient can be installed as a nuget package if you are using .net 4.0 Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http

Comment: @Mihail Shishkov: Thx! Works easy and perfect!

Comment: You welcome. You may want to accept this as the correct answer.